# TinyMCE "EditMenuName" css property is not working after upgrading Episerver to version 11.5

Tags: css, tinymce, episerver

After upgrading **Episerver** to version 11.5, the **TinyMCE** feature of being able to set custom names for menu items in a drop down is no longer working.

The special custom CSS attribute called `EditMenuName` is not working I guess. those menu items only showing particular CSS class names. not the names which are provided as "EditMenuName" attributes.

How do I get this feature working again?

Answer (score 3):

There is no support for this. What you can do instead is to add these items to the `style_formats`, please see https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/content-formatting/#style_formats. More information on how you can customize the editor https://world.episerver.com/documentation/developer-guides/CMS/add-ons/customizing-the-tinymce-editor-v2/.

Here's an example configuration:

```
config
.Default()
.Schema(TinyMceSchema.Html5Strict)
.ContentCss("/gui/css/base.css")
.AddPlugin("link table paste code contextmenu")
.Toolbar(
    "styleselect undo redo pastetext removeformat searchreplace code fullscreen",
    "bold italic numlist bullist outdent indent table epi-link unlink image epi-image-editor epi-personalized-content")
.StyleFormats(
    new { title = "Paragraph", format = "p" },
    new { title = "Header 2", format = "h2" },
    new { title = "Header 3", format = "h3" },
    new { title = "Header 4", format = "h4" },
    new
    {
        title = "Inline",
        icon = "forecolor",
        items = new[]
        {
            new { title = "Strikethrough", format = "strikethrough", icon = "strikethrough" },
            new { title = "Superscript", format = "superscript", icon = "superscript" },
            new { title = "Subscript", format = "subscript", icon = "subscript" },
            new { title = "code", format = "code", icon = "code" }
        }
    },
    new
    {
        title = "Blocks",
        icon = "template",
        items = new[]
        {
            new { title = "Blockquote", format = "blockquote" },
            new { title = "Preformatted", format = "pre" },
        }
    },
    new
    {
        title = "Images",
        icon = "image",
        items = new[]
        {
            new { title = "Left", selector = "img", classes = "left", icon = "alignleft" },
            new { title = "Right", selector = "img", classes = "right", icon = "alignright" },
            new { title = "Full-width", selector = "img", classes = "fullwidth", icon = "alignjustify" }
        }
    },
    new
    {
        title = "Tables",
        icon = "table",
        items = new[]
        {
            new { title = "Left", selector = "table", classes = "left", icon = "alignleft" },
            new { title = "Right", selector = "table", classes = "right", icon = "alignright" },
            new { title = "Full-width", selector = "table", classes = "fullwidth", icon = "alignjustify" }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hi Johan Petersson,

Plese refer this link to see full comment.
https://www.goconqr.com/en-US/notes/13691222/edit

Comment: That link doesn't work. Why not just post the comment here?

Comment: Hi Johan Petersson, 

Thanks for your response. Sorry about the broken link. I want to share my source code with you, that's why I'm trying to use link. because this  comment field has character limitations. Can you please try this link in
Codepen :-  https://codepen.io/eashanxyz/pen/mLKzov?editors=1000

Comment: Update to latest version. Episerver has changed the default behavior now regarding the Styles select. Please see https://world.episerver.com/documentation/Release-Notes/ReleaseNote/?releaseNoteId=CMS-10052.

Comment: Thanks Johan Petersson, appreciate your reply. I'll discuss about this with development team.